# Major memory Leak in Joomla/ PHP .. What gives?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, joomla

```
 }
public function backup(){
    $app =& JFactory::getApplication();
    $createTablesSQL = $this->_dbo->getTableCreate($this->_tables);
    $databaseName = $app->getCfg("db");
    $data = "--\n-- Database: `{$databaseName}`\n--\n\n";
    foreach ($createTablesSQL as $key => $value){
        $data .= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$key}`;\n";
        $data .= "\n--\n-- Table structure for table `{$key}`\n--\n";
        $data .= $value . ";\n";
        $tableFields = $this->_dbo->getTableFields($key);
        $this->_dbo->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `{$key}`");
        $this->_dbo->query();
        if($this->_dbo->getNumRows()){
            $data .= "--\n-- Dumping data for table `{$key}`\n--\n";
            $data .= "LOCK TABLES `{$key}` WRITE;\n";
            $fields = array_keys($tableFields);
            $data .= "REPLACE INTO `{$key}` (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($tableFields[$fields[0]]))."`) VALUES \n";
            // Load data from table
            $rows = $this->_dbo->loadRowList();
            $_ = array();
            foreach ($rows as $row){
                foreach ($row as $k => $v){
                    if(!isset($v))
                        $row[$k] = 'NULL';
                    else
                        $row[$k] = "'".addslashes($v)."'";
                    }
                $_[] = "\t(".implode(", ", $row).")";
            }
            $data .= implode(",\n", $_);
            $data .= ";\nUNLOCK TABLES;\n\n";
        }
    }
    // fix dbprefix after getTableCreate
    $tablePrefix = $app->getCfg("dbprefix");
    $data = str_replace($tablePrefix, "#__", $data);
    // write backup file
    $path2Filename = $this->path2BackupFiles;
    $filename = $this->filePrefix . date("Y_m_d_H_i_s", time()) . "_" . CompanyUpdate::getCurrentVersion() . ".sql";
    if(JFile::write($path2Filename . $filename, $data)){
        // compression
        if(false != ($arFile = $this->compressFile($path2Filename, $filename, 'zip', true))){
            return $arFile;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;    
    }
}
/**
 *
 * @param string $path2Filename
 * @param string $filename
 * @param string $type
 * @param bool $cleanUp
 * @return bool
 */
private function compressFile($path2Filename, $filename, $type = 'zip', $cleanUp = false){
    $fullPathFilename = $path2Filename . $filename;     
    $adapter =& JArchive::getAdapter($type); // type compression
    $files2ZIP = array();
    $files2ZIP[0]["name"] = $filename;
    $files2ZIP[0]["data"] = JFile::read($fullPathFilename);
    if($adapter->create($fullPathFilename . "." . $type, $files2ZIP, $type, $path2Filename)){
        if($cleanUp)
            JFile::delete($fullPathFilename);
        return JFile::stripExt($filename) . "." . $type;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}
?>

Anyone see a leak here somewhere?

EDIT: Should have thought to post the error. Sorry

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 65536000) (tried to allocate 125459 bytes) in /home/user2/public_html/administrator/components/com_company/lib/CompanyBaseDManagement.php on line 395

According to Dreamweaver this is line 395: $row[$k] = "'".addslashes($v)."'";

Comment: post anything like error's code, description, line-number stack trace etc ........ not just the big php file.

Comment: Thanks Ish, just made the edit.

Comment: Jeez, something is going terribly wrong...

Comment: Sorry for getting off topic, but Joomla has always been an outstandingly shining example of programmer's hell on earth. Nick, what happens if you comment out line 395?

Comment: Yes etranger, I feel you. Im not by no stretch of the imaganation a programemr so Joomla made some sense to me. I do agree though, I wouldnt want to stay on joomla for long.. By commenting the line out it just throws off the error before even executing it, it basically throws teh error before i even execute

Comment: Commenting the line out was a silly suggestion, I'm sorry, it obviously broke the syntax and got you an error. The much better suggestion to increase memory limit or use mysqldump to solve this issue is just below.

Answer (score 3):

The whole script is horribly memory inefficient. It should be appending the data out in chunks to the backup file rather than reading the entire damn database into memory and then running a str_replace() on it, then possibly sending that over to a compression function which re-reads the file into memory and compresses it. !!!

Honestly, the only easy way I can see this getting fixed is to up the memory limit in your php.ini file, try 128MB. If your db keeps growing then this number will keep having to go up. It'd be more efficient to scrap that script and use mysqldump + gzip on the command line, if you have access.

Comment: I second this answer on both points: the backup function tries to fetch all the data there is in a database table, and it could easily use up all of the available memory. This must've been only tested on small sets of data. Using mysqldump is the right way to make db backup, and it doesn't take a programmer to do it.

Comment: Hahahah This is by far the most correct (as well as up-front) answer. MySQL dump makes the server do all the work, *not* PHP (which was designed to run scripts, not manage memory for large pieces of data like the DB being pulled here); let `mysqldump` do all the hefty work and leave PHP to do what it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know for a fact that editing an array that is being acted upon by a `foreach` loop (like how that `foreach` loop is in your code) is *very* dangerous. I am surprised it's not throwing an error (I thought for some rea-- wait nevermind, wrong language that throws an error about editing foreach loop arrays). I think there might be an infinite loop there. I have seen instances where a foreach loop would push a new object onto the array it was referencing, ultimately causing an infinite loop (since it never runs out of elements to iterate upon)!

A good place to start would be to separate the array being referenced and a new array with the new values, and then merging them or whatever *after* the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you very sure it's a leak? Not just the backup exceeding your memory limit?
I can't see what the obvious problem is but have you considered putting in some debugging of the memory consumption and loop iteration number around that loop? It could be an iffy row of data which should be very obvious with a sudden jump in consumption

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php